# Not getting response from SslStream.read

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, gmail

I'm trying to do a simple Gmail client.  The problem is that I'm getting a pretty weird response; actually I'm not getting response from `SslStream.read` at all.  First when I connect to the gmail server as client, it works perfectly (`Connect()` method), but then when I'm trying to get the number off emails, again using `SslStream.read` with `leerMensaje()` method, it gets weird and just stops running, and the webpage gets stuck loading.

Here is the class I'm working on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace GmailClient
{
    public class GmailPop
    {
        private SslStream sslStream;
        private String user;
        private String pass;

        public GmailPop(String user, String pass)
        {
            this.user = user;
            this.pass = pass;
        }

        public bool Connect()
        {
            String response;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int bytes = -1;
            TcpClient server = new TcpClient("pop.gmail.com", 995);
            sslStream = new SslStream(server.GetStream());
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.gmail.com");
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer,0,bytes);
            sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("USER recent:" + user+"\r\n"));
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer,0,bytes);
            if(response.StartsWith("+OK")){
                sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PASS "+pass+"\r\n"));
                bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
                response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
                return response.StartsWith("+OK");
            }
            return false;
        }
        public int numCorreos()
        {
            String res = escribirLeer("STAT");
            String[] resA = res.Split(' ');
            int num = Int32.Parse(resA[1]);
            return num;
        }
        public String leerMensaje()
        {
            int bytes = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            String msg = "";
            do
            {
                bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                msg += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
            } while (bytes != 0);
            return msg;
        }
        public void escribirMsg(String msg)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            sslStream.Write(buffer);
            sslStream.Flush();
        }
        public String escribirLeer(String msg)
        {
            escribirMsg(msg);
            String respuesta = leerMensaje();
            return respuesta;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the aspx webpage that calls the method:

```
GmailPop client;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["user"] != null && Session["pass"] != null)
            {
                String user = Session["user"].ToString();
                String pass = Session["pass"].ToString();

                client = new GmailPop(user, pass);

                if (client.Connect())
                {                    
                    Session["active"] = true;
                    Response.Write(numCorreos());
                }
                else
                {
                    Session.Remove("pass");
                    Response.Redirect("login.aspx?error=login");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first issue is that you're sending "STAT" as a command, but all commands must be terminated with "\r\n", so you need instead to send "STAT\r\n".

It would appear that you're also inferring the end of the message by a return code of 0 from `sslStream.Read(...)`, however this method won't return 0 until the stream is closed. In the case where there is no more data waiting to be read, `Read()` will block, waiting for more data to arrive, which explains the hanging you're seeing.

According to the [POP3 protocol specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html), for a single line response, you should be waiting for a "\r\n" sequence to indicate the end of the response, and for those commands that result in multi-line responses (e.g. retrieving message data), the response is terminated by a single "." on a line by itself (i.e. the line begins with ".\r\n"). There are additional rules for handling messages that contain this termination sequence, so I would suggest reading through the protocol specification yourself.

Comment: Yeah i try what you said, and actually I read before the documentation of the read method, and it returns the numbers off bytes that read, so if it at the end off the line it should return  0, the problem is that even debugging the program when it reaches for the first time that instruction it just stop debugging just after it run that line. is a pretty weird behavior.

Comment: The reason that it's hanging the first time you call Read() is because commands must be terminated with "\r\n". You're just sending "STAT", but need instead to send "STAT\r\n". I will edit my answer to reflect this. However my original answer still stands - since the current code still expects Read() to return 0 (which it won't, unless the connection is closed), so even if you send the command correctly, it will still hang, but at the second call to Read() instead.

Comment: Thanks man, that little deatils that we dont see sometimes because you are working midnight after classes. Thanks again